# IN clause in SQL with no value - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have following query used by c# program:

```
var names = string.Join(",", activeNames.Select(n => string.Format("'{0}'", n)).ToArray());

var query = @"SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE NOT Name IN (" + names + ")";
```

The above query works as long as there is value in names like if name = 'Ken', 'John'
this works. But if name is empty query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE NOT Name IN ()
```

which is invalid syntax how can i make this query work?

I can use two seperate queries like: 
`SELECT * FROM TableA`  //if name is empty

or above query if name has values. But is this right way to approch this?

Comment: If you do the right thing and pass arrays as table valued parameters then you end up with an empty parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure that'll work.

```
var query = @"SELECT * FROM TableA"
if(activeNames.length > 0)
  query += " WHERE NOT Name IN (" + names + ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Name` is never empty, you could add an empty value to the `IN` clause:

```
@"SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE NOT Name IN (''," + names + ")";
```

Comment: This only works if you don't actually have a blank name in the DB.

Comment: @PinnyM, I actually specified "If Name is never empty" to avoid this kind of comment...

Answer (score 0):

You can just add validation for the value of the names variable.

```
string query = string.empty;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(names))
{
 query = "SELECT * FROM TableA";
}
else
{
 query = "SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE NOT Name IN ("....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use separate queries. Based on your information, there is no need to hack the `WHERE`-clause.

```
var query = @"SELECT * FROM TableA";
if (activeNames.Any()){
    var names = string.Join(",", activeNames
                                    .Select(n => string.Format("'{0}'", n))
                                    .ToArray());

    query += " WHERE NOT Name IN (" + names + ")";
}
```

But please, **use parameterized queries!** See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause) on how to do this.